# Prometheus query multiple targets

Tags: ansible, prometheus

I have a personal project where I deploy automatically new virtual machines using Ansible on Proxmox and I have also a Prometheus with Grafana instance where I am monitoring the services.

My question is, it is possible to add automatically new targets to prometheus.yml configuration? My vision was to add on prometheus.yml "- targets: 192.168.2.15/24" to query 254 IP addresses but from what I have searched, this is not possible.

Next idea was to add a variable on the ansible playbook after the creation of the virtual machine to get the IP address of the VM and add it to prometheus.yml configuration.

Do you have another approach to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus supports various target discovery mechansism - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html). I think the following ones can be useful for your use case:

- [file_sd_config](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#file_sd_configs)
- [http_sd_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#http_sd_configs)